# Groovy .each closure wrapping elements in an unwanted Object[]

Tags: groovy, closures

I am testing a service which returns a List of Object[]

```
List<Object[]> list = someService.someMethod()
list.each { Object[] row ->
    assertEquals(A_SIZE,row.length)
}
```

I double checked through the debugger, list's element are Object[8], but row is initialized as an Object[1], which contains an Object[8], so the test fails unless A_SIZE is 1 (which is meaningless in my scenario).
If I change the assert to:

```
assertEquals(A_SIZE, row[0].length)
```

the test goes fine, but I don't understand why I need the "[0]", since "row" is supposed to be the Object[8], as far as I understand from Groovy specifications.

I am using groovy 2.1 and grails 2.3M2; the list comes from a MyDomainClass.createCriteria().

Comment: Smells like a bug in Groovy's type coercion... As a workaround, you can use `list.each { row ->`

Comment: It works! Please post the solution as a reply and I will accept it.
Thank you

Comment: Done :-) (with what I believe is the underlying reason for it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Groovy has troubles working out what to do to map the `Object[]` to the Closure parameter.  A workaround is to not declare the type of the Closure parameter like so:

```
list.each { row ->
    assertEquals(A_SIZE,row.length)
}
```

I've asked around, and I think this is because Groovy currently tries to 'fit' the object to the Closure parameters (in the way that this works)

```
// Returns [ 3, 7 ]
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ].collect { a, b ->
    a + b
}
```

There have been debates as to whether Groovy should do this sort of destructuring or not on the mailing list, but for now, it does :-)